# Mapping issue with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two Model classes Author and Book and two DTO classes BookDTO and BookDetailDTO as shown below

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Book 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }           
}

public class BookDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
}

public class BookDetailDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
}
```

I use AutoMapper to do the mapping as shown below

```
public class MapConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMapping()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name)));
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name)).ReverseMap());


        //AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookDetailDTO>()
            //.ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name)));
        //AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookDetailDTO>()
            //.ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name)).ReverseMap());

    }
}
```

Now I get the list of books through  BooksController

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    private BookServiceContext db = new BookServiceContext();


    public IQueryable<BookDTO> GetBooks()
    {

        var books = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Book>, IEnumerable<BookDTO>>(db.Books);
        return books.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

It list the list of books.

But when I un-comment the mappings for BookDetailDTO in MapConfig.cs, and I try to get the list of Books, It throws the following error

> Mapping types: IEnumerable`1 -> IEnumerable`1
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[BookService.Models.Book,
>   BookService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>   -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[BookService.Models.BookDTO,
>   BookService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

I need the mapping from Book to BookDetailDTO to display the details of the book.
What am I doing wrong? I use AutoMapper 5.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one fixed my issue, I think we have to put all mappings inside the initialize method

```
      AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name));
            cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookDetailDTO>()
             .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name));
        });
```

Even though this fixed my problem, I am not sure this is the best way to do it. If any body has better answer to how to map all mappings in a project, please share the same.

Comment: This is the right way to go. You need to call initialize once pre AppDomain (just like you'd initialize your ORM just once, or DI container, etc.). What most people do is initialize AutoMapper through Profiles:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration

Answer (score 0):

1-) You over configured it. I removed the unnecessary parts:

```
public class MapConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMapping()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name)).ReverseMap());


        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookDetailDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name)).ReverseMap());

    }
}
```

2-) Dont use `Mapper.Map` method because `Mapper.Map` executes the query. Instead, use `ProjectTo`. It doesn't execute the query. It edits your ef query. It is better for performance

Install this
[image]

**ProjectTo support returning IQuerable objects**.

```
public IQueryable<BookDTO> GetBooks()
{
    return db.Books.ProjectTo<BookDTO>();
}
```

For More information

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions

Comment: In what way does this answer the question? This should be a comment.

Comment: @Sercan Timocin Thanks for looking into this issue, but there is no ProjectTo method available. Thanks for the info.
I think I am doing some thing wrong with the Mapping.

Comment: I added pic .How you add ;) @SimplyStupid

Answer (score 0):

In the MapConfig class, you defined the map twice, Book -> BookDTO, then Book ->  BookDetailDTO. The second map definition overridden the first definition, automapper will complaint when you call Mapper.Map, IEnumerable>(db.Books), because automapper did not know how to map Book -> BookDTO. That's was the reason you got that error message.

To solve the problem, you either define Book -> BookDTO or Book -> BookDetailDTO, not both.

Comment: I've tested it with either Book->BookDTO or Book->BookDetailDTO, they worked as expected. @SimplyStudpid try it then mark this as an answer. If you have any issue please ask. Thanks.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that Book->BookDTO works, but I need to map the same to BookDetailDTO. The requirement is like this, display list of books. select a book, It should display the details of the book. Both refer to the same model.